# Validating HTML Form

Tags: javascript, optimization, html, form, validation

I am trying to create a simple validation for forms.  I am almost there, but there are few bugs and optimization errors that I am really struggling with.  I'm looking for advice on how to make this function simpler and more understandable.

```
var errorMessage = {
   required: "This field can not be empty",
   email: "Please enter a valid email address",
   number: "Please only enter numbers in this field",
   min: "This field should be minimum ",
   max: "This field should be maximum ",
   date: "Please use the date format outlined above"
};

var $form = $("#contactForm");
var $formInputs = $("#contactForm input");
var $formTextareas = $("#contactForm textarea");
var $formSelects = $("#contactForm select");
var currentRadioSet = "";

$form.submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (submitValidate()) {
      var $el = $(this);
      $submit = $el.find('button[id="submit"]');
      $inputs = $el.find('input, textarea, select, label');
      $.post($el.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function(data) {
         $('span.error').remove();
         if (data) {
            $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
            $submit.add($inputs).addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
         } else {
            $submit.after('<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 15px 5px; color: #bd3d3d">Failed to send the message, please try again later.</span>');
            $submit.text('Try Again');
         }
      });
   }
});

$formInputs.keyup(function() {
   var $el = $(this);
   if (!$el.hasClass("required")) {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
   }
   checkForClasses($el);
});

$formTextareas.keyup(function() {
   var $el = $(this);
   if (!$el.hasClass("required")) {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
   }
   checkForClasses($el);
});

$formTextareas.blur(function() {
   var $el = $(this);
   if (!$el.hasClass("required")) {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
   }
   checkForClasses($el);
});

$formInputs.blur(function() {
   var $el = $(this);
   if (!$el.hasClass("required")) {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
   }
   checkForClasses($el);
});

function submitValidate() {
   resetErrorMessages();

   $formInputs.each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      checkForClasses($el);
   });

   $formTextareas.each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      checkForClasses($el);
   });

   $formSelects.each(function() {
      var $el = $(this);
      checkForClasses($el);
   });

   if (!$('.error').length) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}

function checkForClasses(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var isValid = true;
   isValid = checkForMin($el);
   if (!isValid) {
      return;
   }
   isValid = checkForMax($el);
   if (!isValid) {
      return;
   }
   if ($el.hasClass("required")) {
      isVaild = requiredVal($el);
      if (!isValid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   if ($el.hasClass("email")) {
      isVaild = emailVal($el);
      if (!isValid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   if ($el.hasClass("number")) {
      isVaild = numberVal($el);
      if (!isValid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   if ($el.hasClass("date")) {
      isVaild = dateVal($el);
      if (!isValid) {
         return;
      }
   }
}

function requiredVal(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   if ($el.is(':radio:last') || $el.is(':checkbox:last')) {
      currentRadioSet = $el.attr("name");
      valid = $("input[name=" + currentRadioSet + "]:checked").val();
   }

   if ($.trim($el.val()) == "" || !valid) {
      manageErrorMessage($el, errorMessage.required);
      valid = false;
   } else {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
      valid = true;
   }


   return valid;
}

function numberVal(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   var numRegEx = /^\d+$/;
   var numIn = $.trim($el.val());
   if (!$.trim($el.val()) == "") {
      if (!numRegEx.test(numIn)) {
         manageErrorMessage($el, errorMessage.number);
         valid = false;
      } else {
         resetSingleErrorMessage($el)
         valid = true;
      }
   }
   return valid;
}

function emailVal(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   var emailRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
   var emailIn = $.trim($el.val());
   if (!$.trim($el.val()) == "") {
      if (!emailRegEx.test(emailIn)) {
         manageErrorMessage($el, errorMessage.email);
         valid = false;
      } else {
         resetSingleErrorMessage($el)
         valid = true;
      }
   }
   return valid;
}

function dateVal(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   var dateRegEx = /^(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/\-](0?[1-9]|1[012])[\/\-]\d{4}$/;
   var dateIn = $.trim($el.val());
   if (!$.trim($el.val()) == "") {
      if (!dateRegEx.test(dateIn)) {
         manageErrorMessage($el, errorMessage.date);
         valid = false;
      } else {
         resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
         valid = true;
      }
   }
   return valid;
}

function checkForMin(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   if ($el.attr("class")) {
      if ($el.attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/)) {
         var minClass = $el.attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/).toString();
         minVal = parseInt(minClass.match(/[0-9]+/));
         if ($.trim($el.val().length) < minVal) {
            manageErrorMinMax($el, errorMessage.min, minVal);
            valid = false;
         } else {
            resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
            valid = true;
         }
      }
   }
   return valid;
}

function checkForMax(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   var valid = true;
   if ($el.attr("class")) {
      if ($el.attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/)) {
         var maxClass = $el.attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/).toString();
         maxVal = parseInt(maxClass.match(/[0-9]+/));

         if ($.trim($el.val().length) > maxVal) {
            manageErrorMinMax($el, errorMessage.max, maxVal);
            valid = false;
         } else {
            resetSingleErrorMessage($el);
            valid = true;
         }
      }
   }
   return valid;
}

function manageErrorMessage(elementIn, errorMessageIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   $el.addClass('error');
   if (!$el.next().is("span")) {
      $el.after('<span class="error"></span>');
   }
   $el.next().html(errorMessageIn);
}

function manageErrorMinMax(elementIn, errorMessageIn, value) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   $el.addClass('error');
   if (!$el.next().is("span")) {
      $el.after('<span class="error"></span>');
   }
   $el.next().html(errorMessageIn + value + " charaters long.");
}

function resetSingleErrorMessage(elementIn) {
   var $el = $(elementIn);
   $el.removeClass("error");
   if ($el.next().is("span")) {
      $el.next().remove();
   }
}

function resetErrorMessages() {
   $("span.error").remove();
   $("input .error").removeClass("error");
}
```

1. The script is really ugly and not optimized at all which is what causing some problems as I can't just understand what is what and which is which, therefore I am now trying to clean it up.  I am not an expert in JavaScript but have basic knowledge - the script is the results of a very long nights researching and collecting things and putting them together...

   **A)** I cleaned up this bit:

   ```
   var $form = $("#contactForm");
   var $formInputs = $("#contactForm input");
   var $formTextareas = $("#contactForm textarea");
   var $formSelects = $("#contactForm select");
   var currentRadioSet = "";
   ```

   so now it appears like this:

   ```
   var $form = $("form");
   var $inputs = $("input, textarea, select, label");
   ```

   **B)** I have accompanied all the key-up and blur together "This is for a feel of a real-time validation":

   ```
   $inputs.keyup(function () {
       var $element = $(this);
       if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
           resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
       }
       checkForClasses($element);
   });

   $formTextareas.keyup(function () {
       var $element = $(this);
       if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
           resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
       }
       checkForClasses($element);
   });

   $formTextareas.blur(function () {
       var $element = $(this);
       if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
           resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
       }
       checkForClasses($element);
   });

   $inputs.blur(function () {
       var $element = $(this);
       if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
           resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
       }
       checkForClasses($element);
   });
   ```

   So now they appear like this:

   ```
   $inputs.bind('blur keyup focus', function(){
       var $element = $(this);
       if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
           resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
       }
       checkForClasses($element);
    });
   ```

   **C)** I also cleaned up this section that I believe it validates on submit:

   ```
   function validate() {
       resetErrorMessages();

       $inputs.each(function () {
           var $element = $(this);
           checkForClasses($element);
       });

       $formTextareas.each(function () {
           var $element = $(this);
           checkForClasses($element);
       });

       $formSelects.each(function () {
           var $element = $(this);
           checkForClasses($element);
       });

       if (!$('.error').length) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   So it appear like this now:

   ```
   function validate() {
       resetErrorMessages();
       $inputs.each(function () {
           var $element = $(this);
           checkForClasses($element);
       });
       if (!$('.error').length) {
           return true;
       } else {
           return false;
       }
   }
   ```

   **D** I have also cleaned this bit up, this section check if the inputs has any classes and then pass it to validate.

   ```
   function checkForClasses(elementIn) {
       var $el = $(elementIn);
       var isValid = true;
       isValid = checkForMin($el);
       if (!isValid) {
           return;
       }
       isValid = checkForMax($el);
       if (!isValid) {
           return;
       }
       if ($el.hasClass("required")) {
           isVaild = requiredVal($el);
           if (!isValid) {
               return;
           }
       }
       if ($el.hasClass("email")) {
           isVaild = emailVal($el);
           if (!isValid) {
               return;
           }
       }
       if ($el.hasClass("number")) {
           isVaild = numberVal($el);
           if (!isValid) {
               return;
           }
       }
       if ($el.hasClass("date")) {
           isVaild = dateVal($el);
           if (!isValid) {
               return;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   It is now appearing like:

   ```
   //Check for validation rules in inputs
   function checkForClasses(element) {
       var $element = $(element);
       var valid = true;

   //check for required
   if ($element.hasClass("required")) {
       valid = Required($element);
       if (!valid) {
           return;
       }
   }
   //check for email
   if ($element.hasClass("email")) {
       valid = Email($element);
       if (!valid) {
           return;
       }
   }
   //check for number
   if ($element.hasClass("number")) {
       valid = Number($element);
       if (!valid) {
           return;
       }
   }
   //check for minimum
   valid = Minimum($element);
   if (!valid) {
       return;
   }
   //check for maximum
   valid = Maximum($element);
   if (!valid) {
       return;
   }
   ```

   }

Why does Man and Min not work if I did them as all the others?  If I used this method, they won't work.

```
if ($element.hasClass("max")) {
           valid = Maximum($element);
          if (!valid) {
             return;
          }
       }
```

Is there any way to clean this section farther and make it simpler?  The form has to be dynamic and I can't seem to be able to figure out away to make it check for classes dynamically without telling it where to go manually.

I just don't know what to do with the rest of the code.  Every time I try to optimize it, it breaks.  Please can someone help me?

Some of the bugs: I can't validate radio and checkbox buttons, and the validation for the select input only works when submit not in a real time.

Here is the final code after cleaning up:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('form').length > 0) {
var errorMessage = {
    required:  "This field can not be empty",
    email:     "Please enter a valid email address",
    number:    "This field can only contain numbers",
    min:       "This field should be minimum ",
    max:       "This field should be maximum ",
};
var $form = $("form");
var $inputs = $("input, textarea, select, label");
$form.submit(function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   if (validate()) {
   var $element = $(this);
   $submit = $element.find('button[id="submit"]');
   $inputs = $element.find('input, textarea, select, label');
   $.post($element.attr('action'), $form.serialize(),
      function (data) {
         $('span.error').remove();
         if (data) {
            $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
            $submit.add($inputs).addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
         } else {
            $submit.text('Try Again');
         }
      });
   }
});
//Check for validation rules in inputs
function checkForClasses(element) {
   var $element = $(element);
   var valid = true;
   //check for required
   if ($element.hasClass("required")) {
       valid = Required($element);
      if (!valid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   //check for email
   if ($element.hasClass("email")) {
       valid = Email($element);
      if (!valid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   //check for number
   if ($element.hasClass("number")) {
       valid = Number($element);
      if (!valid) {
         return;
      }
   }
   //check for minimum
   valid = Minimum($element);
   if (!valid) {
      return;
   }
   //check for maximum
   valid = Maximum($element);
   if (!valid) {
      return;
   }
}
//Real-time validation
$inputs.bind('blur keyup focus', function(){
   var $element = $(this);
   if (!$element.hasClass("required")) {
      resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
   }
   checkForClasses($element);
});
//Validate on submit
function validate() {
   resetErrorMessages();
   $inputs.each(function () {
      var $element = $(this);
      checkForClasses($element);
   });
   if (!$('.error').length) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
}
//Required - validation rule
function Required(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var valid = true;
    if ($element.is(':radio:last') || $element.is(':checkbox:last')) {
        currentRadioSet = $element.attr("name");
        valid = $("input[name=" + currentRadioSet + "]:checked").val();
    }
    if ($.trim($element.val()) == "" || !valid) {
        manageErrorMessage($element, errorMessage.required);
        valid = false;
    } else {
        resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
        valid = true;
    }
    return valid;
}
//Email - validation rule
function Email(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var valid = true;
    var emailRegEx = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    var emailIn = $.trim($element.val());
    if (!$.trim($element.val()) == "") {
        if (!emailRegEx.test(emailIn)) {
            manageErrorMessage($element, errorMessage.email);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            resetSingleErrorMessage($element)
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
//Number - validation rule
function Number(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var valid = true;
    var numRegEx = /^\d+$/;
    var numIn = $.trim($element.val());
    if (!$.trim($element.val()) == "") {
        if (!numRegEx.test(numIn)) {
            manageErrorMessage($element, errorMessage.number);
            valid = false;
        } else {
            resetSingleErrorMessage($element)
            valid = true;
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
//Minimum - validation rule
function Minimum(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var valid = true;
    if ($element.attr("class")) {
        if ($element.attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/)) {
            var minClass = $element.attr("class").match(/min[0-9]+/).toString();
            minVal = parseInt(minClass.match(/[0-9]+/));
            if ($.trim($element.val().length) < minVal) {
                manageErrorMinMax($element, errorMessage.min, minVal);
                valid = false;
            } else {
                resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
//Maximum - validation rule
function Maximum(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    var valid = true;
    if ($element.attr("class")) {
        if ($element.attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/)) {
            var maxClass = $element.attr("class").match(/max[0-9]+/).toString();
            maxVal = parseInt(maxClass.match(/[0-9]+/));
            if ($.trim($element.val().length) > maxVal) {
                manageErrorMinMax($element, errorMessage.max, maxVal);
                valid = false;
            } else {
                resetSingleErrorMessage($element);
                valid = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return valid;
}
//Show and hide error messages
function manageErrorMessage(element, errorMessageIn) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.addClass('error');
    if (!$element.next().is("span")) {
        $element.after('<span class="error"></span>');
    }
    $element.next().html(errorMessageIn);
}
function manageErrorMinMax(element, errorMessageIn, value) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.addClass('error');
    if (!$element.next().is("span")) {
        $element.after('<span class="error"></span>');
    }
    $element.next().html(errorMessageIn + value + " charaters long.");
}
function resetSingleErrorMessage(element) {
    var $element = $(element);
    $element.removeClass("error");
    if ($element.next().is("span")) {
        $element.next().remove();
    }
}
function resetErrorMessages() {
    $("span.error").remove();
    $("input .error").removeClass("error");
}
}
});
```

**Here is the HTML of the form:**

```
   <form action="contact.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contactForm">

      <div class="name">
         <p>Your Name</p>
         <input class="required" name="name">
      </div>

      <div class="email">
         <p>Email Address</p>
         <input class="required email" name="email">
      </div>

      <div class="number">
         <p>Number</p>
         <input class="required number" name="number">
      </div>

      <div class="message">
         <p>Message</p>
         <textarea class="required min5 max10" name="message" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="dropdown">
         <select class="required">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            <option value="option">Option</option>
         </select>
      </div>

      <div class="radio">
         <p>Radios:</p>
         <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="value">radio</label> 
         <label><input name="sex" type="radio" value="value">radio</label>
      </div>

      <div class="checkbox">
         <p>Checkboxs:</p>
         <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="value">checkbox</label> 
         <label><input name="checkbox" type="checkbox"value="value">checkbox</label>

      </div><button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a once over:

- Function names in JavaScript should only start with a capital if they are constructors, so `Number` is no good, since it returns a boolean, I would call it  `isNumber()`
- I would put a `"use strict";` after `$(document).ready(function () {`
- `if (!$.trim($element.val()) == "") {` should be 
  `if ($.trim($element.val()) != "") {` ( put the `!` in the comparison ).
- `$submit`, `currentRadioSet`, `minVal` and `maxVal` were not declared with `var`
- From a design perspective, it does not seem right that your validation rules manage errors and can reset error messages, in my mind, that should be done elsewhere (`checkForClasses`?), this will reduce a lot copy of paste code
- For `Minimum` and `Maximum`, I would advise to get and set the minimum/maximum throught the `$().data()` mechanism instead of classnames and regexes.
- In `checkForClasses` you already do `var $element = $(element);` and then in each validation function you do again `var $element = $(element);`, that is overkill.
- I would only check for minimum and maximum if the `Number` class is present
- Use either single or double quotes for strings, dont mix, ideally use single quotes
- In `validate()` you can simply
  `return !$('.error').length;`
- Also, you are again doing `var $element = $(this);` in `validate()` :D
- Please use jshint.com to self review your code, a lot of this feedback comes from there.